# Identify origin of POST request in Django (Active Campaign)

Tags: django, webhooks, activecampaign

I have set up a webhook to receive POST requests from the Active Campaign API in order to update my CRM data.

The problem is that Active Campaign doesn't send any token or credential information with the POST request, so I cannot be sure that the request is really coming from them.

Is there a way in Django to check where the request is coming from, in order to prevent anyone from sending POST data to this webhook?

Comment: You can check headers, you can check anything/everything inside the request, BUT if they're not sending you a secret that you both agreed on -- it will be a pretty big security hole.. To be fair i have no idea how sensitive this data is...

Comment: Looks like when you add the webhook you specify the FULL url, this is exactly what you need: https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=webhook_add when you POST `url` send something like: `https://yourdomain/api/v1/your/uri/?api_key=1234567890`, i would STRONGLY suggest you use django-rest-framework it has built in token api authentication see here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication